# How to remove 2 types of files from a directory?

Tags: terminal, bash-scripting

How do you delete all files of two different types?

e.g.,

rm Downloads/*.jpg but I also want to delete all the .png files as well?

I tried rm Downloads/*.jpg *.png but that didn't work neither did adding a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ways:

- `rm Downloads/*.jpg Downloads/*.png` - specify the directory each time
- `cd Downloads; rm *.jpg *.png` - once you're in the directory, you don't need to specify it again
- `rm Downloads/*.{jpg,png}` - use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)